# How do I implement polling using Observables?

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have a parametrized rest call that should be executed every five seconds with different params:

```
Observable<TResult> restCall = api.method1(param1);
```

I need to create an `Observable<TResult>` which will poll the restCall every 5 seconds with different values for param1. If the api call fails I need to get an error and make the next call in 5 seconds. The interval between calls should be measured only when restCall is finished (success/error).

I'm currently using RxJava, but a .NET example would also be good.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Introduction

First, an admission, I'm a .NET guy, and I know this approach uses some idioms that have no direct equivalent in Java. But I'm taking you at your word and proceeding on the basis that this is a great question that .NET guys will enjoy, and that hopefully it will lead you down the right path in rx-java, which I have never looked at. This is quite a long answer, but it's mostly explanation - the solution code itself is pretty short!

## Use of Either

We will need sort some tools out first to help with this solution. The first is the use of the `Either<TLeft, TRight>` type. This is important, because you have two possible outcomes of each call *either* a good result, or an error. But we need to wrap these in a single type - we can't use OnError to send errors back since this would terminate the result stream. Either looks a bit like a Tuple and makes it easier to deal with this situation. The [Rxx library](http://rxx.codeplex.com/) has a very full and good implementation of `Either`, but here is a simple generic example of usage followed by a simple implementation good for our purposes:

```
var goodResult = Either.Right<Exception,int>(1);
var exception = Either.Left<Exception,int>(new Exception());

/* base class for LeftValue and RightValue types */
public abstract class Either<TLeft, TRight>
{
    public abstract bool IsLeft { get; }
    public bool IsRight { get { return !IsLeft; } }
    public abstract TLeft Left { get; }
    public abstract TRight Right { get;  }    
}

public static class Either
{
    public sealed class LeftValue<TLeft, TRight> : Either<TLeft, TRight>
    {
        TLeft _leftValue;

        public LeftValue(TLeft leftValue)
        {
            _leftValue = leftValue;
        }

        public override TLeft Left { get { return _leftValue; } }
        public override TRight Right { get { return default(TRight); } }
        public override bool IsLeft { get { return true; } }
    }

    public sealed class RightValue<TLeft, TRight> : Either<TLeft, TRight>
    {
        TRight _rightValue;

        public RightValue(TRight rightValue)
        {
            _rightValue = rightValue;
        }

        public override TLeft Left { get { return default(TLeft); } }
        public override TRight Right { get { return _rightValue; } }
        public override bool IsLeft { get { return false; } }
    }

    // Factory functions to create left or right-valued Either instances
    public static Either<TLeft, TRight> Left<TLeft, TRight>(TLeft leftValue)
    {
        return new LeftValue<TLeft, TRight>(leftValue);
    }

    public static Either<TLeft, TRight> Right<TLeft, TRight>(TRight rightValue)
    {
        return new RightValue<TLeft, TRight>(rightValue);
    }
}
```

Note that by convention when using Either to model a success or failure, the Right side is used for the successful value, because it's "Right" of course :)

### Some Helper Functions

I'm going to simulate two aspects of your problem with some helper functions. First, here is a factory to generate parameters - each time it is called it will return the next integer in the sequence of integers starting with 1:

```
// An infinite supply of parameters
private static int count = 0;
public int ParameterFactory()
{
    return ++count; 
}
```

Next, here is a function that simulates your Rest call as an IObservable. This function accepts an integer and:

- If the integer is even it returns an Observable that immediately sends an OnError.
- If the integer is odd it returns a string concatenating the integer with "-ret", but only after a second has passed. We will use this to check the polling interval is behaving as you requested - as a pause between completed invocations however long they take, rather than a regular interval.

Here it is:

```
// A asynchronous function representing the REST call
public IObservable<string> SomeRestCall(int x)
{
    return x % 2 == 0
        ? Observable.Throw<string>(new Exception())
        : Observable.Return(x + "-ret").Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));   
}
```

### Now The Good Bit

Below is a reasonably generic reusable function I have called `Poll`. It accepts an asynchronous function that will be polled, a parameter factory for that function, the desired rest (no pun intended!) interval, and finally an IScheduler to use.

The simplest approach I could come up with is to use `Observable.Create` that uses a scheduler to drive the result stream. `ScheduleAsync` is a way of Scheduling that uses the .NET async/await form. This is a .NET idiom that allows you to write asynchronous code in an imperative fashion. The `async` keyword introduces an asynchronous function that can then `await` one or more asynchronous calls in it's body and will continue on only when the call completes. [I wrote a long explanation of this style of scheduling in this question, which includes the older recursive the style that might be easier to implement in an rx-java approach.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489004/ischeduler-schedule-vs-ischeduler-scheduleasync) The code looks like this:

```
public IObservable<Either<Exception, TResult>> Poll<TResult, TArg>(
    Func<TArg, IObservable<TResult>> asyncFunction,
    Func<TArg> parameterFactory,
    TimeSpan interval,
    IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.Create<Either<Exception, TResult>>(observer =>
    {
        return scheduler.ScheduleAsync(async (ctrl, ct) => {
            while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = await asyncFunction(parameterFactory());
                    observer.OnNext(Either.Right<Exception,TResult>(result));
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    observer.OnNext(Either.Left<Exception, TResult>(ex));
                }
                await ctrl.Sleep(interval, ct);
            }
        });        
    });    
}
```

Breaking this down, `Observable.Create` in general is a factory for creating IObservables that gives you a great deal of control over how results are posted to observers. It's often overlooked in favour of unnecessarily complex composition of primitives.

In this case, we are using it to create a stream of `Either<TResult, Exception>` so that we can return the successful and failed polling results.

The `Create` function accepts an observer that represents the Subscriber to which we pass results to via OnNext/OnError/OnCompleted. We need to return an `IDisposable` within the `Create` call - in .NET this is a handle by which the Subscriber can cancel their subscription. It's particularly important here because Polling will otherwise go on forever - or at least it won't ever `OnComplete`.

The result of `ScheduleAsync` (or plain `Schedule`) is such a handle. When disposed, it will cancel any pending event we Scheduled - thereby ending the the polling loop. In our case, the `Sleep` we use to manage the interval is the cancellable operation, although the Poll function could easily be modified to accept a cancellable `asyncFunction` that accepts a `CancellationToken` as well.

The ScheduleAsync method accepts a function that will be called to schedule events. It is passed two arguments, the first `ctrl` is the scheduler itself. The second `ct` is a CancellationToken we can use to see if cancellation has been requested (by the Subscriber disposing their subscription handle).

The polling itself is performed via an infinite while loop that terminates only if the CancellationToken indicates cancellation has been requested.

In the loop, we can use the magic of async/await to asynchronously invoke the polling function yet still wrap it in an exception handler. This is so awesome! Assuming no error, we send the result as the *right* value of an `Either` to the observer via `OnNext`. If there was an exception, we send that as the *left* value of an `Either` to the observer. Finally, we use the `Sleep` function on the scheduler to schedule a wake-up call after the rest interval - not to be confused with a `Thread.Sleep` call, this one typically doesn't block any threads. Note that Sleep accepts the `CancellationToken` enabling that to be aborted as well!

I think you'll agree this is a pretty cool use of async/await to simplify what would have been an awfully tricky problem!

### Example Usage

Finally, here is some test code that calls `Poll`, along with sample output - for [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) fans all the code together in this answer will run in LINQPad with Rx 2.1 assemblies referenced:

```
void Main()
{
    var subscription = Poll(SomeRestCall,
                            ParameterFactory,
                            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                            ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
        .TimeInterval()                            
        .Subscribe(x => {
            Console.Write("Interval: " + x.Interval);
            var result = x.Value;
            if(result.IsRight)
                Console.WriteLine(" Success: " + result.Right);
            else
                Console.WriteLine(" Error: " + result.Left.Message);
        });

    Console.ReadLine();    
    subscription.Dispose();
}

Interval: 00:00:01.0027668 Success: 1-ret
Interval: 00:00:05.0012461 Error: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
Interval: 00:00:06.0009684 Success: 3-ret
Interval: 00:00:05.0003127 Error: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
Interval: 00:00:06.0113053 Success: 5-ret
Interval: 00:00:05.0013136 Error: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
```

Note the interval between results is either 5 seconds (the polling interval) if an error was immediately returned, or 6 seconds (the polling interval plus the simulated REST call duration) for a successful result.

EDIT - Here is an alternative implementation that *doesn't* use ScheduleAsync, but uses old style recursive scheduling and no async/await syntax. As you can see, it's a lot messier - but it does also support cancelling the asyncFunction observable.

```
    public IObservable<Either<Exception, TResult>> Poll<TResult, TArg>(
        Func<TArg, IObservable<TResult>> asyncFunction,
        Func<TArg> parameterFactory,
        TimeSpan interval,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Create<Either<Exception, TResult>>(
            observer =>
                {
                    var disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
                    var funcDisposable = new SerialDisposable();
                    bool cancelRequested = false;
                    disposable.Add(Disposable.Create(() => { cancelRequested = true; }));
                    disposable.Add(funcDisposable);
                    disposable.Add(scheduler.Schedule(interval, self =>
                        {
                            funcDisposable.Disposable = asyncFunction(parameterFactory())
                                .Finally(() =>
                                    {
                                        if (!cancelRequested) self(interval);
                                    })
                                .Subscribe(
                                    res => observer.OnNext(Either.Right<Exception, TResult>(res)),
                                    ex => observer.OnNext(Either.Left<Exception, TResult>(ex)));
                        }));

                    return disposable;

                });
    }
```

See my other answer for a different approach that avoids .NET 4.5 async/await features and doesn't use Schedule calls.

I do hope that is some help to the rx-java guys!

Comment: No problem - fun question. I've made some minor edits to add additional explanation and improve code formatting.

Comment: James what about replacing scheduler.ScheduleAsync with delayed version of Observable and subscribing to its result

Comment: Delay will give you a one time delay. It gets very tricky handling OnErrors and introducing a loop on top of that - I've always ending up with very convoluted Rx chains going that route. ScheduleAsync (or just plain Schedule) is great when you need lots of control. But maybe someone can see an easy way?

Comment: I have added an alternative method that uses an old-style recursive Schedule call without async/await syntax, it also supports cancellation of the asyncFunction.

Comment: Added RetryWithDelay - I think this is probably what you were getting at above... it needs wrapping with an Observable.Create, but I'm guessing this will be the easiest to translate to rx-java. You do need to think through the implications of the Do side-effect calls with multiple subscribers though.

Comment: Moved the non-Schedule code to a second answer, as it's really a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Rxx, very interesting judging by the documentation!

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't use `Observable.Interval` in your implementation?

Comment: Yes this was a very deliberate decision because the requirement called for a 5s interval measured from the *end* of one invocation to the *start* of the next. Using `Observable.Interval` would not account for the execution time of call. If you think about it, there's no reasonable way to make a general-purpose Observable operator work this way because it requires implicit downstream knowledge - of handler durations in this case - in a model that doesn't offer feedback (On... methods return void). Also, what would be reasonable behaviour for multiple subscribers? A special handling is needed.

Comment: I'll just leave a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222978/translating-a-piece-of-asynchronous-c-sharp-code-to-f-with-reactive-extensions) here to the piece of code that uses ``Interval``. It's in F#, but readable even for an unaccustomed eye, I think.

Comment: @JamesWorld, thanks for elaborating. One way to handle multiple subscriptions would be to use `.Publish().RefCount()`.

Comment: Yes that can be a very useful pattern. I wrote about it in a bit more depth [here](http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=144)

Answer (score 2):

I've cleaned up the approach that *doesn't* use the Schedule call directly - using the Either type from my other answer - it will also work with the same test code and give the same results:

```
    public IObservable<Either<Exception, TResult>> Poll2<TResult, TArg>(
        Func<TArg, IObservable<TResult>> asyncFunction,
        Func<TArg> parameterFactory,
        TimeSpan interval,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Create<Either<Exception, TResult>>(
            observer =>
                Observable.Defer(() => asyncFunction(parameterFactory()))
                          .Select(Either.Right<Exception, TResult>)
                          .Catch<Either<Exception, TResult>, Exception>(
                            ex => Observable.Return(Either.Left<Exception, TResult>(ex)))
                          .Concat(Observable.Defer(
                            () => Observable.Empty<Either<Exception, TResult>>()
                                            .Delay(interval, scheduler)))
                          .Repeat().Subscribe(observer));
    }
```

This has proper cancellation semantics.

#### Notes on implementation

- The whole construction uses a Repeat to get the looping behaviour.
- The initial Defer is used to ensure a different parameter is passed on each iteration
- The Select projects the OnNext result to an Either on right side
- The Catch projects an OnError result to an Either on the left side - note that this exception terminates the current asyncFunction observable, hence the need for repeat
- The Concat adds in the interval delay

My opinion is that the scheduling version is more readable, but this one doesn't use async/await and is therefore .NET 4.0 compatible.