# How to transform an exception to an event and to resubscribe to the faulted IObservable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

How should one approach on transforming exceptions in an `IObservable` stream to plain domain objects and to resubscribe to the stream transparently?

**Addendum:** As [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87427/james-world) points out in the comment, my use case idea was something like having a *should-be continuous stream* over an unreliable source, e.g. a network. In case of a glitch, just try to reconnect to the source, but notify the downstream processor.

In fact, this relates my other question at [Translating a piece of asynchronous C# code to F# (with Reactive Extensions and FSharpx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222978/translating-a-piece-of-asynchronous-c-sharp-code-to-f-with-reactive-extensions), which in turn stems from [How to implement polling using Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547880/how-to-implement-polling-using-observables).

In fact, now that I think of it, I could first use code at [How to write a generic, recursive extension method in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404185/how-to-write-a-generic-recursive-extension-method-in-f) ("[RetryAfterDelay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978523/write-an-rx-retryafter-extension-method)") (with some more parameters to adjust the `RetryAfterDelay` behavior) and chain it with this implementation. When the retries are exhausted, a domain error will be produced and the poller will be reinitiated. Granted, there problably will be a more efficient way, but nevertheless. :) ... Or provide just a call-back function to log error instead of transforming them to *domain events*, well, choices abound...

But back to the original code...

For instance, if I have

```
public enum EventTypeEnum
{
    None    = 0,
    Normal  = 1,
    Faulted = 2
}

public class Event
{
    public EventTypeEnum Type { get; set; }
} 

private static IObservable<int> FaultingSequence1()
{
    var subject = new ReplaySubject<int>();
    subject.OnNext(1);
    subject.OnNext(2);
    subject.OnError(new InvalidOperationException("Something went wrong!"));

    return subject;
}

private static IEnumerable<int> FaultingSequence2()
{                           
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        yield return 1;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Something went wrong!");
}

//Additional pondering: Why isn't FaultingSequence2().ToObservable() too be procted by Catch?
//
//This part is for illustratory purposes here. This is the piece I'd like
//behave so that exceptions would get transformed to Events with EventTypeEnum.Faulted
//and passed along to the stream that's been subscribed to while resubscribing to 
//FaultingSequence1. That is, the subscribed would learn about the fault through a
//domain event type.
//Retry does the resubscribing, but only on OnError.
var stream = FaultingSequence1().Catch<int, Exception>(ex =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
    return Observable.Throw<int>(ex);
}).Retry().Select(i => new Event { Type = EventTypeEnum.Normal });

//How to get this to print "Event type: Normal", "Event type: Normal", "Event type: Faulted"?
stream.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("Event type: {0}", i.Type));
```

This problem has really got me now! Any advice?

Comment: As an aside, do be sure to differentiate conceptually between "exceptions in the stream" and a stream terminating in error. The language you have chosen there is suggestive of a failure not in the stream itself (which would be something akin to an infrastructure problem), but in the business logic of the application. If you are dealing with "business logic" exceptions, these are often best handled as data of the stream - e.g. using the Either monad (a classic frp concept implemented in the Rxx library). More...

Comment: I'm sure you know this, and that you are talking about genuine "infrastructure" type errors - but just wanted to highlight this point to avoid readers falling into the trap of using OnError inappropriately.

Comment: Hmm, I added a note regarding this. I was rather exhausted when I tried to produce a F# version of your code, but instead of ``Either``, use ``Choice``, the F# equivalent. This all is a bit clearer now, until the kids drive me deeper into sleep deprivation, uh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an operator called [`Materialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229453(v=vs.103).aspx) which converts each event into a [`Notification<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.notificationkind(v=vs.103).aspx):

```
OnNext:
    OnNext a Notification<T> with Kind OnNext containing a value.

OnError:
    OnNext a Notification<T> with Kind OnError containing an exception.
    OnCompleted.

OnCompleted:
    OnNext a Notification<T> with Kind OnCompleted
    OnCompleted.
```

So the subscription still completes when either OnError or OnCompleted is invoked, but OnError is never invoked on the Subscriber. So you could be able to do something like this...

```
source
    .Materialize()
    .Repeat();
```

However, this will resubscribe to the source *even when the original subscription completes naturally (via OnCompleted)*.

So maybe you still want OnError to be invoked, but you also want the exception from the original OnError to be passed through OnNext inside of a `Notification<T>`. For that, you could use something like this:

```
source
    .Materialize()
    .SelectMany(notification => 
        notification.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError
            ? Observable.Return(notification).Concat(Observable.Exception(notification.Exception))
            : Observable.Return(notification)
    )
    .Retry();
```

In this manner, if the subscription completes naturally (via OnCompleted), then the source will not be resubscribed.

Once you have that set up, it's each enough to map each type of notification to whatever domain object you want to use:

```
source
    .Materialize()
    .SelectMany(notification => 
        notification.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError
            ? Observable.Return(notification).Concat(Observable.Exception(notification.Exception))
            : Observable.Return(notification)
    )
    .Retry()
    .Map(notification => {
        switch (notification.Kind) {
            case (NotificationKind.OnNext):      return // something.
            case (NotificationKind.OnError):     return // something.
            case (NotificationKind.OnCompleted): return // something.
            default: throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This was a very throughout explanation. Cheers! This ``Materialize`` business is somewhat new to me, but one reads good explanations and learns!