# RxJava: calling onError without finishing / unsubscribing

Tags: error-handling, rx-java

I have the following code(*) that implements polling using a scheduler that recursively calls the supplied observable.

(*) inspired from https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/448

This is working correctly when I only pass the `onNext` event to the subscriber. But when I pass the `onError` event to the subscriber, the unsubscribe event is called and this in turn kills the scheduler.

I'd like to also pass the errors to the subscriber. Any ideas how to achieve that?

```java
public Observable<Status> observe() {
    return Observable.create(new PollingSubscriberAction<>(service.getStatusObservable(), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}

private class PollingSubscriberAction<T> implements Observable.OnSubscribe<T> {
    private Subscription subscription;
    private Subscription innerSubscription;
    private Scheduler.Worker worker = Schedulers.newThread().createWorker();

    private Observable<T> observable;
    private long delayTime;
    private TimeUnit unit;

    public PollingSubscriberAction(final Observable<T> observable, long delayTime, TimeUnit unit) {
        this.observable = observable;
        this.delayTime = delayTime;
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    @Override
    public void call(final Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
        subscription = worker.schedule(new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                schedule(subscriber, true);
            }
        });

        subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                subscription.unsubscribe();
                if (innerSubscription != null) {
                    innerSubscription.unsubscribe();
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    private void schedule(final Subscriber<? super T> subscriber, boolean immediately) {
        long delayTime = immediately ? 0 : this.delayTime;
        subscription = worker.schedule(createInnerAction(subscriber), delayTime, unit);
    }

    private Action0 createInnerAction(final Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
        return new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                innerSubscription = observable.subscribe(new Observer<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        schedule(subscriber, false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        // Doesn't work.
                        // subscriber.onError(e);
                        schedule(subscriber, false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(T t) {
                        subscriber.onNext(t);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've been playing with this one for some time, and I don't think it's possible in the way you're doing it. Calling `onError` or `onCompleted` terminate the stream, flipping the `done` flag within the `SafeSubscriber` wrapper, and there just isn't a way to reset it.

I can see 2 options available - neither I think are particularly elegant, but will work.

1 - `UnsafeSubscribe`. Possibly not the best idea but it works, because instead of wrapping your `Subscriber` in a `SafeSubscriber`, it calls it directly. Best read the [Javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/SafeSubscriber.html) to see if this is OK for you. Or, if you're feeling adventurous write your own `SafeSubscriber` where you can reset the done flag or similar. With your example, call like:

```
observe.unsafeSubscribe(...)
```

2 - Implement something similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547880/how-to-implement-polling-using-observables). I appreciate it's in C#, but it should be readable. Simply put - you want to create a `Pair<T, Exception>` class, and then rather than calling `onError`, call `onNext` and set the exception side of your pair. Your subscriber will have to be a little more clever to check for each side of the pair, and you might need to do some data transformation between your source `Observable` and the `Observable<Pair<T, Exception>>`, but I can't see why it won't work.

I'd be really interested in seeing another way of doing this if anyone has any.

Hope this helps,

Will

Comment: Can you give example with unsafeSubscribe()? A simple method call does not help solve the problem.

Comment: @Alexandr This answer is a year old and the API has changed quite a bit since then, so it's possible this no longer works. Besides, the solution documented by the OP is probably better. I would either use that solution if your problem is identical, or post a new question.

Answer (score 6):

Both onError and onCompleted are terminating events, what means that your Observable won't emit any new events after any of them occurrs. In order to swallow/handle error case see error operators - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators. Also, in order to implement polling you might take advantage of this one - http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html

Answer (score 3):

As @Will noted, you can't directly call `onError` without terminating the observable. Since you can only call `onNext`, I decided to use a [Notification](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Notification.html) to wrap the value and the throwable in a single object.

```java
import rx.*;
import rx.functions.Action0;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
import rx.subscriptions.Subscriptions;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PollingObservable {
    public static <T> Observable<Notification<T>> create(Observable<T> observable, long delayTime, TimeUnit unit) {
        return Observable.create(new OnSubscribePolling<>(observable, delayTime, unit));
    }

    private static class OnSubscribePolling<T> implements Observable.OnSubscribe<Notification<T>> {
        private Subscription subscription;
        private Subscription innerSubscription;
        private Scheduler.Worker worker = Schedulers.newThread().createWorker();

        private Observable<T> observable;
        private long delayTime;
        private TimeUnit unit;

        private boolean isUnsubscribed = false;

        public OnSubscribePolling(final Observable<T> observable, long delayTime, TimeUnit unit) {
            this.observable = observable;
            this.delayTime = delayTime;
            this.unit = unit;
        }

        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Notification<T>> subscriber) {
            subscription = worker.schedule(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    schedule(subscriber, true);
                }
            });

            subscriber.onStart();
            subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    isUnsubscribed = true;

                    subscription.unsubscribe();
                    if (innerSubscription != null) {
                        innerSubscription.unsubscribe();
                    }
                }
            }));
        }

        private void schedule(final Subscriber<? super Notification<T>> subscriber, boolean immediately) {
            if (isUnsubscribed) {
                return;
            }

            long delayTime = immediately ? 0 : this.delayTime;
            subscription = worker.schedule(createInnerAction(subscriber), delayTime, unit);
        }

        private Action0 createInnerAction(final Subscriber<? super Notification<T>> subscriber) {
            return new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    innerSubscription = observable.subscribe(new Observer<T>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            schedule(subscriber, false);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            subscriber.onNext(Notification.<T>createOnError(e));
                            schedule(subscriber, false);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(T t) {
                            subscriber.onNext(Notification.createOnNext(t));
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

To use this, you can either use the notification directly:

```java
PollingObservable.create(service.getStatus(), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribe(new Action1<Notification<Status>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Notification<Status> notification) {
            switch (notification.getKind()) {
                case OnNext:
                    Status status = notification.getValue();
                    // handle onNext event
                    break;
                case OnError:
                    Throwable throwable = notification.getThrowable();
                    // handle onError event
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Or you can use the [accept](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Notification.html#accept(rx.Observer)) method on the notification to use a regular Observable:

```java
PollingObservable.create(service.getStatus(), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribe(new Action1<Notification<Status>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Notification<Status> notification) {
               notification.accept(statusObserver);
            }
        });

Observer<Status> statusObserver = new Observer<Status>() {
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE 2015-02-24**

It seems that the polling observable wasn't working correctly sometimes, because the inner observable would call `onComplete` or `onError` even after it had been unsubscribed, thus rescheduling itself. I added the `isUnsubscribed` flag to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Really like the use of the notification class - much cleaner than using a Pair etc.